# How to mask the image in C# using ITextSharp.dll?

Tags: c#, image, itext, mask

I am newbie to C#.Can anybody provide me with some links or tutorials for the masking of the image using ITextSharp.dll?

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter10/ImageMask.cs

http://learn-vsdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/03/replacemask-images-of-pdf-file-using.html

Comment: It's a pity this question was closed because there's a clear answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm discussing hard and soft image masks in [chapter 10](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=10) of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/). You'll find some Java examples (and the corresponding PDFs) if you click links such as [ImageMask](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=189) (this example shows you how to create a [hard mask](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter10/hardmask.pdf) as well as a [soft mask](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter10/softmask.pdf)). You'll find a C# port of the examples here: http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH10